# Xcode pass Array by using segue

Tags: arrays, xcode, segue

I made an array and put some values into it.

And by using segue,

I want to send the array to another view.

Here are codes.

**----- View1 -----**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var receivedData: Array<String> = Array()
    receivedData.append("0.123")
    receivedData.append("0.190")
    receivedData.append("0.210")
    receivedData.append("0.213")
}


 @IBAction func graph(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{

        if segue.destination is GraphViewController
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? GraphViewController
            vc?.transferedData = receivedData
        }

}
```

**----- View2 -----**

```
var transferedData: Array<String> = Array()
```

But it doesn't work.

There are **errors** likes

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance"
>
> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
>   reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance "
>
> " libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have to declare `receivedData` on the top level of the class. And what is `graph(for segue`?

Comment: I want to draw a graph by using "Charts" lib. So I had named segue as graph.

Comment: And What is meaning of "declare receivedData on the top level of the class"?
Should i have to declare on the View2?

Comment: *top level* means outside of `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

The reference of `receivedData` array will not accessible outside `viewDidLoad()` method which you have created. you have to declare it as a global array for that class, then you can access that array throughout your class.

---

Please declare `receivedData` outside of `viewDidLoad()` function. Please do following.

```
var receivedData: Array<String> = Array()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    receivedData.append("0.123")
    receivedData.append("0.190")
    receivedData.append("0.210")
    receivedData.append("0.213")
}
```